# the name does not exist in current context C#

Tags: c#, .net, variables, timer, scope

I have an error in my code where it says `the name "line" does not exist in current context`. I know why and its because the `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);` isn't declared inside of `public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` however I do not know how to fix this since I'm new to  C#. I have searched the forum and googled it but I cant seem to find anything for my situation, I know this is probably really simple.

Below is a snippet of my code where the problem is:

```
 public void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            timer1.Start();

        }
        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int lineNumber = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.TextLength);

            try
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++)
                {

                    if (lines[i].Contains("LCD"))
                    {
                        label1.Text = lines[i].Remove(0, 6);
                    }
                    if (lines[i].Contains("laser") && lines[i].Contains("On"))
                    {
                        pictureBox4.Show();
                    }
                    if (lines[i].Contains("laser") && lines[i].Contains("Off"))
                    {
                        pictureBox4.Hide();
                    }
                    if (lines[i].Contains(".end"))
                    {
                        button2.PerformClick();
                    } 

                } 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Form3", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

I know that I can put  `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);` in `public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` but then it will only read the first line of the Document every time.

Comment: You need to read about "Scope".  But a quick fix to your problem is move the declaration `string[] lines;` outside of your method.  The line right above `public void button13_Click` will work, although I prefer toward the top of the program.  Again...Read about scope to find out why this is the case.  Be sure to leave `lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);` where you have it (without the `string[]` portion)

Comment: Thanks! but now i have a problem with openFileDialog1.FileName which says that "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property ''"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
private string[] lines;
public void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Here, we've declared the `lines` array so that it has class scope. But we initialize it in the `button13_Click` event handler.

Comment: thanks! now its all error free, id upvote you if my rep wasnt so d*mn low

Comment: @olleolofsson: If this answered your question, click the check mark there to mark it as the accepted answer.